# Count relationship for multiple models coming from the same model

Tags: laravel

I have the following three models: User, Post and Comment. A User can have multiple posts and each post can have multiple comments.

What I would like to do is:

- Get the count of all comments across all posts that belong to a specific user
- Get the count of all comments for this month across all posts that belong to that same user
- The starting point is a specific Post by ID (so not starting from a User ID).

See below what I have now, and this works.

My question is: is it possible to add the last two lines doing ->sum() to the query?

I think this query is already quite a beauty but it would look even better, but more importantly it will make caching a lot easier, if those last 2 lines are included as well.

```
$post = Post::findOrFail($id);

$posts = Post::where('user_id', $post->user_id)
        ->withCount(['comments as comments_total'])
        ->withCount([
            'comments as comments_this_month' => function ($q) {
                $q->whereBetween('created_at',
                    [ Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth() ]
                );
            },
        ])->get();
});

$comments_this_month_count = $posts->sum('comments_this_month');
$comments_total_count = $posts->sum('comments_total');
```

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a better solution with two line of code only.

Define a `hasManyThrough` Relation in your `User` Model:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Comment::class,
        Post::class,
        'user_id', // Foreign key on posts table...
        'post_id' // Foreign key on comments table...
    );
}
```

Then just call it like this:

```
$comments_this_month_count = User::find($post->user_id)->comments()
->whereMonth('created_at', now()->month)->count();

$comments_total_count = User::find($post->user_id)->comments()->count();
```

Comment: Using a `HasManyThrough` is a good idea. Although now I'm still left with 2 lines of code for the 2 counts, like I have now. If I can put them in 1 query is easier to cache, although I probably have to increment these counts anyway.